# I have two questions about relating events to functions

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

What does the following expression mean?

> variable.DOMevent = function

Why does it not fire up `handler1` and only fires up `handler2`?

```js
var a = document.querySelector("a");

var container1 = a;
container1.onmouseover = container1.onmouseout = handler1;

var container2 = a;
container2.onmouseover = container2.onmouseout = handler2;

function handler1 (event) {
   console.log('handler1: '+event.type);   
}

function handler2 (event) {
   console.log('handler2: '+event.type);   
}
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>hover me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `onmouseover` of the element. Both `container1` and `container2` are still pointing to the same anchor element. Assigning to different variables won't make any difference.

To fix this, you could create a new `superHandler` function which will call the other handler functions inside it.

```js
function handler1(event) {
  console.log('handler1: ' + event.type);
}

function handler2(event) {
  console.log('handler2: ' + event.type);
}

function superHandler(e) {
  handler1(e)
  handler2(e)
}

const a = document.querySelector("a");

a.onmouseover = a.onmouseout = superHandler;
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>hover me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: "You are overwriting the onmouseover of the element.". What do you mean by this? The rest was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @user3291759 `container1` and and `container2` are the same element `a`. This element has a `onmouseover` property. It is like doing `a.onmouseover = handler1` and then  `a.onmouseover = handler2`. The `onmouseover` property of the element is set to `handler2`

Answer (score 0):

`container1` and `container2` refers to the same object, so you are just overwriting the callback for the event listener.

If for example you target two different elements, you will be able to see both the callbacks

```js
var a = document.querySelector("a");
var b = document.querySelector("span");

var container1 = a;
container1.onmouseover = container1.onmouseout = handler1;

var container2 = b;
container2.onmouseover = container2.onmouseout = handler2;

function handler1 (event) {
   console.log('handler1: '+event.type);   
}

function handler2 (event) {
   console.log('handler2: '+event.type);   
}
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>hover me 1</a>
  <span>hover me 2</span>
</div>
```